# C# Finding the maximum value of a string with linq

Tags: c#, string, linq, max

This is what I have and it keeps returning null.

It doesn't recognize the Convert.toInt32 when I add a where statement

```
var maxTopID = (from max in dbcontext.Topics.Local
               select max.TopicID).Max();
```

Comment: where is your `where` statement? where is your `Covnert.ToInt32`?

Comment: Do you have values in TopicId ? what is the data type of TopicId ?

Comment: yep!  100, 200, 300, 400, and 500

Comment: with the where statement it read
     var maxTopID = 
          (from max in dbcontext.Topics.Local
           where Convert.ToInt32(max.TopicID)
           select max.TopicID).Max();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about converting the `TopicID` in `SELECT` and use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to remove empty string, like:

```
 var maxTopID = (from max in dbcontext.Topics.Local
                 where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(max.TopicID)
                 select Convert.ToInt32(max.TopicID)).Max();
```

See the <kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/u6tZTp)</kbd>

Comment: Does LINQ to SQL support `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`? I am pretty it doesn't support `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`, but does it support the former one I am not sure.

Comment: Did you check the **Demo** link? That's straight from a C# compiler. Also `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` could be use anywhere as long as you're testing a value if it is `null` or empty.

Comment: I visited that link, but didn't bother to run it, because that has nothing to do with my question. To be explicit, that doesn't involve LINQ to SQL. Nevermind, I will check myself tomorrow, and let you know, if I remember that is. After all, the OP isn't about LINQ to SQL itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the null condition as mentioned in below query

```
var maxTopID = (from max in dbcontext.Topics.Local
                 where  max.TopicId != null
                 select max.TopicID).Max();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that `TopicID` is string and you want to convert it to int

```
var list= (from max in dbcontext.Topics.Local
                     where  max.TopicId != null
                     select max.TopicID).ToList();

int max=0;

if (list.Count() !=0)
max=list.Select(int.Parse).ToList().Max();
```

max will contain max value from list which is converted to list of integer